# how to start docker service with a specific port in linux (ubuntu/centos)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, centos

I'm just trying to start Docker service with a specific port which is running in ubuntu server for add to monitoring service PRTG. But I couldn't find a way to start Docker with a specific port. Does any one have started docker service with a specific port in linux?

Comment: do you want to start the service on its own on a specific port or the running container?

Comment: yes Gabbax0r I want to start the service on its own on a specific port

Comment: Why not just monitor the port it started on with PRTG instead of changing the port?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you unaccepted my ans?

Comment: Sorry Yuri L it mistakenly happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you want is to have Docker listening on a `tcp` socket.

To do this you will need to configure the Docker daemon on your host machine.

The method depends on whether the Ubuntu host is using sysvinit/upstart or [systemd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options).

If you are using sysvinit/upstart you will need to edit the file `/etc/default/docker`
add the environment variable `DOCKER_OPTS` and add the options that you want.

You will need to setup a private key and certificate for the Docker daemon which is covered in the PRTG [documentation](https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/67250-how-can-i-create-private-key-and-certificate-for-the-docker-sensor).

Make sure to add all the options that are listed to the `DOCKER_OPTS` in the 
`/etc/default/docker` file.

Comment: Thank you Yuri L this is working for me. And is there are any way to add wildcard certificate to Docker service.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are restart policies. You want to achieve that a container starts in a specified port on Docker daemon start, so you have to specify `restart=always`, which will try to start the container any time that it's restarted (for example, on system startup).

You can achieve this by the following command. This will start an `ubuntu` container in host port 80 (bounded to port 8000 of the container) and will restart it on every restart.

`docker run --restart=always -p 80:8080 ubuntu`

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 ubuntu bash
```

This binds port 8080 of the container to port 80 on 127.0.0.1 of the host machine.
https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

Comment: Thank you Sergaros. But this bind Docker container locally to 80 and 8080 inside a container.  My requirement is getting up Docker service with a port in a local server.

Comment: I'm not understand what do you want.

Comment: I want to bind a port when Docker service getting start.EX : (/etc/init.d/docker start)

Comment: you don't start docker on a particular port this way